# How to get value from URL in a view block using contextual filter?

Tags: 7, views, nodes, blocks

I want to show related nodes of an open article in a block, but how do I access Node IDs from url in block view.

Comment: Here's a good tutorial: [ click here](https://www.dannyenglander.com/blog/using-views-contextual-filters-create-related-content-block-drupal-7) Note that in the example, he's filtering OUT the current node, but filtering FOR nodes that match the current node's taxonomy terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your article is located at `node/nid` (with `nid` the id of the node of the article), then configure your contextual filter like so:

> When the filter value is not available: Provide a default value with Type = "Content ID from URL" (that value should correspond to the `nid` of your article).